# How to separate datetime string into date and time in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, date, datetime, pyspark, time

I read this CSV file

| PurchaseDatetime | PurchaseId |
| --- | --- |
| 29/08/2020 10:09:01 | 9 |
| 5/10/2020 7:02 | 4 |
| 5/10/2020 9:00 | 6 |
| 20/06/2020 02:11:36 | 4 |
| 23/10/2020 07:02:15 | 3 |
| 6/2/2020 10:10 | 7 |

You can see, rows number 2, 3 and 6 are different from others.
When I open this CSV in Excel, I find these rows in this format  *8/12/2022 12:00:00 AM*.

I try to clean the data and create separate Date and Time columns.

```py
df=df.withColumn("PurchaseDate",to_date(col("PurchaseDatetime"),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")).withColumn("PurchaseTime",date_format("PurchaseDatetime","dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"))
```

I want to get this output:

| PurchaseDate | Purchasetime | PurchaseId | PurchaseDatetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29-08-2020 | 10:09:01 | 9 | 29/08/2022 10:09:01 |
| 05-10-2020 | 07:02:00 | 4 | 5/10/2020 7:02 |
| 05-10-2020 | 09:00:00 | 6 | 5/10/2020 9:00 |
| 20-06-2020 | 02:11:36 | 4 | 20/06/2020 02:11:36 |
| 23-10-2020 | 07:02:15 | 3 | 23/10/2020 07:02:15 |
| 06-02-2020 | 10:10:00 | 7 | 6/2/2020 10:10 |

But unfortunately I get this:

| PurchaseDate | Purchasetime | PurchaseId | PurchaseDatetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29-08-2020 | null | 9 | 29/08/2020 10:09:01 |
| 05-10-2020 | null | 4 | 5/10/2020 7:02 |
| 05-10-2020 | null | 6 | 5/10/2020 9:00 |
| 20-06-2020 | null | 4 | 20/06/2020 02:11:36 |
| 23-10-2020 | null | 3 | 23/10/2020 07:02:15 |
| 06-02-2020 | null | 7 | 6/2/2020 10:10 |

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

`date_format` will convert your column into string containing your specified format. But first, Spark needs to understand what time is in your column. It only understands strings in correct format ('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' or 'yyyy-MM-dd'). Since your string has a different format, first you need to convert your string into a timestamp using `to_timestamp`. However, since you have different string formats, in some rows you will have nulls, so `coalesce` will attempt another conversion with different parameters in those rows.

Example input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('29/08/2020 10:09:01', 9),
     ('5/10/2020 7:02', 4),
     ('5/10/2020 9:00', 6),
     ('20/06/2020 02:11:36', 4),
     ('23/10/2020 07:02:15', 3),
     ('6/2/2020 10:10', 7)],
    ['PurchaseDatetime', 'PurchaseId'])
```

Script:

```py
time = F.coalesce(
    F.to_timestamp('PurchaseDatetime', 'd/M/yyyy H:mm:ss'),
    F.to_timestamp('PurchaseDatetime', 'd/M/yyyy H:mm')
)
df = df.withColumn("PurchaseDate", F.to_date(time)) \
       .withColumn("PurchaseTime", F.date_format(time, 'HH:mm:ss'))
df.show()
# +-------------------+----------+------------+------------+
# |   PurchaseDatetime|PurchaseId|PurchaseDate|PurchaseTime|
# +-------------------+----------+------------+------------+
# |29/08/2020 10:09:01|         9|  2020-08-29|    10:09:01|
# |     5/10/2020 7:02|         4|  2020-10-05|    07:02:00|
# |     5/10/2020 9:00|         6|  2020-10-05|    09:00:00|
# |20/06/2020 02:11:36|         4|  2020-06-20|    02:11:36|
# |23/10/2020 07:02:15|         3|  2020-10-23|    07:02:15|
# |     6/2/2020 10:10|         7|  2020-02-06|    10:10:00|
# +-------------------+----------+------------+------------+
```